# Await returns an object, but when fetching the values they're undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous

I'm trying to fetch a value from my firebase DB and I'm using the following code:

```
export const getCode = async key => {
  let ref = await database.ref ('games/' + key).once('value');
  console.log(ref);
  console.log(ref.code);
  return ref;
};
```

The results I get from each console.log are these:

the `ref` returns

```
Object {
  "code": 665195,
  "users": Object {
    "-MA5m0PrOWUuz-KdcmRx": Object {
      "username": "לעג",
    },
  },
}
```

but `ref.code` returns `undefined`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZjXh.png)

I've spent hours on my code and stackoverflow and couldn't find an answer. Hopefully you could.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `console.log(ref.code)` shows `undefined`? Can you show a screenshot? I think what's more likely is that you _do_ get `665195` but the next line is an error `code is not defined` ("not defined" is not the same as "undefined"!), which is because there is no variable `code` in your code. You probably want `return ref.code` instead, or alternatively `const code = ref.code` before the `return code`.

Comment: Yeah so I fixed it above and changed it to "return ref".
The problem is the console.logs, I can't get my hands on `ref.code`.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your console.

Comment: Added it in the original post

Comment: That is a weird output, it's not a regular object. It seems it's a custom inspect representation. So [maulikdhameliya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62447216/1871033) probably solves it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't use ref.val() to get values.

try

```
export const getCode = async key => {
      let ref = await database.ref('games/' + key).once('value');
      const data = ref.val();
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.code);
      return data.code;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the `ref` variable be returned? You haven't declared anything named `code` hence why it's undefined.

```
export const getCode = async key => {
  let ref = await database.ref ('games/' + key).once('value');
  return ref.code;
};
```

You could also do like the cool kids and make this single line if you are gonna use it as it is.

```
export const getCode = async key => await database.ref ('games/' + key).once('value').code
```

Comment: Or `return ref.code` probably, since the function is called `getCode`

Comment: Well, I've tried that, it's still undefined.
The point is that "code" is a key inside the returned object, but when I try to use it specifically it's undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I'm now seeing that I'm returning "code" instead of "ref". But that's not what my question is about. Please only look at the console.log 's

Answer (score 0):

If `ref` gets logged as the following:

```
Object {
  "code": 665195,
  "users": Object {
    "-MA5m0PrOWUuz-KdcmRx": Object {
      "username": "לעג",
    },
  },
}
```

I suspect that it could be that you're getting a json string as a response, unless your development environment quotes keys by default.

Maybe try `let ref = JSON.parse(await database.ref ('games/' + key).once('value'));`